# Is there any useful literature about $ \mathbb R $-compactness of almost simple factors of $ \operatorname{Spin}(p, q) $?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

For my thesis about strong approximation, I use Theorem 5.10.6 from [Poonen - Rational points on Varieties](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf).
In the thesis, I am dealing with a generic (nondegenerate) four-dimensional quadratic form $ q $ and an "easy" quadratic form $ q_0 = X_0 X_3 - X_1 X_2 $.

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I construct $ \widetilde{\SO}(q) $, the universal cover of $ \SO(q) $ (and therefore, I believe, $ \mathbb R $-isomorphic to the indefinite spin group $ \Spin(m, 4 - m) $ for some $ m $), as an $ L $-twist of $ \widetilde{\SO}(q_0) \cong_{\mathbb Q} \SL_2 \times \SL_2 $, for $ L $ equal to the field $ \mathbb Q $, with some square roots added.

For Theorem 5.10.6 to work, I need for each almost simple factor of $ \widetilde{\SO}(q) $, a place $ v $ such that $ \widetilde{\SO}(q_0)(\mathbb Q_v) $ is not compact.
I chose the real place, which works for $ q $ with signature $ (2, 2) $ by $ \mathbb R $-isomorphism to $ \SL_2 $ or $ \SL_2 \times \SL_2 \cong \widetilde{\SO}(q_0) $. However, for other $ q $, we only have a $ \mathbb C $-isomorphism, which does not say anything about compactness of the $ \mathbb R $-points.

I did a google search for "compactness of real points of an algebraic group" and things like that, but this mostly yields information about Lie groups and manifolds.

Is there literature or are there results that could shed light on the compactness problem and/or on the almost simple factors of $ \Spin(m, 4 - m) $? If not, that is also okay, I can weaken the final theorem in my thesis to only work for signature $ (2, 2) $, but it would be better if I could prove that all almost simple factors of the spin groups have noncompact sets of $ \mathbb R $-points (which feels true, but does not seem to be very well described).

Comment: You probably already know this, but, just in case you don't, the purely algebraic version of "compact group of rational points" is anisotropic(-ity): a reductive $\mathbb R$-group has compact (in the analytic topology) group of $\mathbb R$-points if and only if it possesses no non-trivial $\mathbb R$-split torus.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with real groups to comment on this particular problem, but I'll bet the tables in Tits's article or Springer's book can answer.

Comment: ([Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438420/is-there-any-useful-literature-about-mathbb-r-compactness-of-almost-simple#comment1130516_438420), Tits's article: [Classification of algebraic semisimple groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.1090/pspum/009/0224710); Springer's book: [Linear algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4840-4).)

Comment: For any quaternary (non-degenerate) quadratic form over a number field, at all but finitely-many places the quadratic form is isotropic, so the local points of the orthogonal group are non-compact. Is this the sort of thing you want, or am I failing to understand some subtleties...? :)

Comment: ... also, if this is something you're wanting, _all_ p-adic orthogonal groups for spaces of dimension $\ge 5$ are non-compact...  This and my previous remark boil down to looking at quaternion algebras over global and local fields (for example), which is well documented...

Comment: And the Platonov-Rapinchuk book "Algebraic groups and number theory" is fairly encyclopedic... though sometimes making things more complicated in order to be sure to treat general cases. :) There is also the "Book of Involutions", by Knus, Merkurjev, Rost, and Tignol. Maybe overkill.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you! I did not know about anisotropicity, nor about the article and book you mentioned.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thank you! The dimension $ \geq 5 $ case unfortunately does not apply here, but it is good to know. Also, isotropicity at all but finitely many points does not give me what I need, but may be good to look into. Lastly, I actually know Theorem 5.10.6 from Platonov-Rapinchuk, but I did not read the rest of the book. I will look into that.